# AJAX request not finding model id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to call an ajax method on my index page which updates an attribute. The attribute is updated (successfully) on a page refresh as the task (this is for a to do list app) is moved from the incomplete list to the complete list. However, when calling the ajax request using a button click, I receive the following error on my rails console:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Task with 'id'=:id [WHERE "tasks"."user_id" = ?]):
  app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:47:in `complete'
```

Here is my ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

console.log("working");


$('.task_submit_box').click(function() {

  $.ajax({url: 'tasks#complete', type: "PATCH", success: function(result) {
    $('.task_area').html(result);
console.log('test');
  }});

});

});
```

my controller method:

```
def complete
    @task = current_user.tasks.find(params[:id])
    @task.update_attribute(:completed_at, Time.now)
    @task.update_attribute(:completed, true)



    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

My index page area where it should be updated:

```
<ul class="wrapper_task_list">
    <% @task.each do |task| %>


    <% if task.completed == false %>
    <li>
      <div class="task_area", id="incomplete_task_area">
      <%= link_to task.title, task_path(task), class: 'wrapper_task_name'%>
      <%= form_for task, remote: true do |f| %>
        <%= f.check_box :completed, class: 'task_check_box' %>
        <%= f.submit 'update', class: 'task_submit_box' %>
      <% end %>
      </div>
    </li>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

I'm lost in trying to match the ajax request with the correct task/:id. my routes specifically mention the url listed in the ajax request:

```
PATCH  /tasks/:id/complete(.:format)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Where's my id?

> `$.ajax({url: 'tasks#complete'`

You seem to be using Rails' route syntax here. Those are not valid urls. Your url must look like this:

```
 url: "/tasks/1/complete"
```

where number should be dynamic, of course. (hint: just fetch form's `action` attribute and use that as url).

#### How to actually do things correctly here?

See that `remote: true` there? It means that you don't have to manually handle submit clicks. It will perform ajax for you. You just have to create a JS view, where you will do whatever it is you do when item is completed.

```
 // views/tasks/complete.js.erb
 $('#task-<%= @task.id %>').addClass('completed')
```

Section [14.2.5](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#sec-a_working_follow_button_with_ajax) of Michael Hartl's rails tutorial covers almost this exact scenario: ajax-powered button that changes something and changes have to be reflected on the page.

Comment: I changed the url to "/tasks/:id/complete" (as specified in the rake routes command) but receive the same error. I see you mention adding an action attribute to the form_for tag but am unfamiliar with this method. Could you please explain in further detail? Thank you

Comment: @snovosel: nah, I don't mention _adding_ action attribute to the form. It's already there. On your page, inspect the form element in your browser console, you'll see that attribute.

Comment: yes I read the second part of the answer. I'm trying to figure out how to add that code to my complete.js.erb (located in /views/tasks). I apologize as I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: @snovosel being new is not something you should apologize for. :) You might want to (re-)read Hartl's rails tutorial. Specifically, section [14.2.5](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#sec-a_working_follow_button_with_ajax).

Comment: thanks so much! I'll look into that. Thanks again for your help !